# How can I add a license for one file from a github repository?

Tags: mit, license-recommendation, copyright, license, github

I would like to use a text file from a GitHub repository that is under MIT License.

My repository is private and I'm distributing my software. My question is how can I use this file and put the right license on my repo?

I read that I should create a LICENSE.md in the same directory as the text file and it should be clearly indicated which file this license applies to. Is that right?

If so, basically I have to only edit [year] and [fullname] tags on the MIT license text, like below:

> MIT License
>
> Copyright (c) [year] [fullname]
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
> a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
> "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
> without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
> distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
> permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
> the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
> included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
> EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
> MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
> IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
> CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
> TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
> SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Comment: Is it just this one file with MIT license, or will the rest of your software be the same? Have you read this answer https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/11409/24836 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a file that is a code, add in the comments in this one file the entire MIT license with copyright notices.

If the file is text/markdown/html (in HTML you can also do solution described above), just create NOTICE(.md) file in global directory with that license (and notices). You can add github repo URL optionally.

If your software is distributed under MIT license you can just copyright notice to the global LICENSE(.md) file from repo you used. ([How to put Copyright notice If I use several other code bases (MIT)](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13412/how-to-put-copyright-notice-if-i-use-several-other-code-bases-mit/13536#13536))

**It is not a legal advice**